# Помогите составить цикл для расчёт границ интервалов

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, выборка

Нужно чтобы программа выводила список левых и правых границ заданного количества интервалов.
Я смог это написать, но нужно чтобы расчёт был в виде цикла. Пытался его составить, но у меня не получается.
Помогите.

[sample1.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2oA8/2yi8tVVRT)

Пример кода:

```
import csv
import math

Sample=[]
with open("sample1.csv", encoding="ANSI") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V, delimiter = ";")
    for row in SR:
        Sample.append(float(row[0]))
print(sorted(Sample))

aggregate=Sample

# Объём выборки
N=len(aggregate)
print("Объём выборки (N): ", N)

# Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов группировки
m=1+(math.log10(N)/math.log10(2))
print("Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов (m): ", "%.0f" % m)

# Наибольшее и наименьшее значение выборки
min_volue=min(aggregate)
max_volue=max(aggregate)
print("Наименьшее значение выборки (min volue): ", min_volue)
print("Наибольшее значение выборки (max volue): ", max_volue)

# Ввод кол-во интервалов группировки
kol_interval=int(input("Введите кол-во интервалов (kol_interval): "))

# Величина интервала
delta=((max_volue-min_volue)/kol_interval)
print("Величина интервала (delta): ", "%.0f" % delta)

c0=min_volue
c1=min_volue+1*delta
c2=min_volue+2*delta
c3=min_volue+3*delta
c4=min_volue+4*delta
c5=min_volue+5*delta
c6=min_volue+6*delta
c7=min_volue+7*delta
c8=min_volue+8*delta
print("1-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c0, "до ", "%.0f" % c1, "\n"
      "2-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c1, "до ", "%.0f" % c2, "\n"
      "3-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c2, "до ", "%.0f" % c3, "\n"
      "4-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c3, "до ", "%.0f" % c4, "\n"
      "5-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c4, "до ", "%.0f" % c5, "\n"
      "6-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c5, "до ", "%.0f" % c6, "\n"
      "7-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c6, "до ", "%.0f" % c7, "\n"
      "8-й интервал: от ", "%.0f" % c7, "до ", "%.0f" % c8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import math

Sample=[]
with open("sample1.csv") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V, delimiter = ";")
    for row in SR:
        Sample.append(float(row[0]))
print(sorted(Sample))

aggregate=Sample

# Объём выборки
N=len(aggregate)
print("Объём выборки (N): ", N)

# Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов группировки
m=1+(math.log10(N)/math.log10(2))
print("Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов (m): ", "%.0f" % m)

# Наибольшее и наименьшее значение выборки
min_volue=min(aggregate)
max_volue=max(aggregate)
print("Наименьшее значение выборки (min volue): ", min_volue)
print("Наибольшее значение выборки (max volue): ", max_volue)

# Ввод кол-во интервалов группировки
kol_interval=int(input("Введите кол-во интервалов (kol_interval): "))

# Величина интервала
delta=((max_volue-min_volue)/kol_interval)
print("Величина интервала (delta): ", "%.0f" % delta)

for i in range(8):
    c0 = min_volue + delta * i
    c1 = min_volue + delta * (i + 1)
    print(f"{i + 1}-й интервал: от {c0} до {c1}")
```